# How to write multiple results to pop up in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to find a way to write results from a network ping test to a pop up window, using powershell. I found a way to write one result at a time, but that is not helpful. I am reading computer names and IPs from an xml file to get the addresses to ping.
My code is:

```
foreach($Computer in $Name.HostSystem){
if(test-connection  $Computer.IPAddress -Count2 - Quiet){
Write-Host $Computer.name :   $Computer.IPAddress "is receiving"
}else{
Write-Host $Computer.name : $Computer.IPAddress "is NOT receiving"
continue
}
}
```

What I would like is a pop up after the code finishes that tells me which computers received and which ones did not, if that's possible, with just an OK button to confirm. I am pinging anywhere from 5 to 20 computers at a time, so a pop up for each result would be too time consuming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To present all your results at once, simply assign them to a single variable:

```
$Output = ForEach($Computer in $Name.HostSystem) {
    If(test-connection  $Computer.IPAddress -Count 2 -Quiet) {
        $Result = "Receiving"
    }
    Else{
        $Result = "Not Receiving"
    }
    [pscustomobject]@{Computer = $Computer;IPAddress = $Computer.IPAddress;Result = $Result}
}
```

Do you mean a GUI popup box? If so then the simplest method is to send the results to a gridview:

```
$output | Out-Gridview
```

Comment: That works perfectly, and is exactly what I needed! Thank you!

Comment: You can mark it as the answer if you dont need anything more

Comment: I think I did now. I hit the checkmark, and I think that's right (I'm new to posting here).